# Symbolic computation a polynomial from Neville's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods, polynomials

I am working on Neville's algorithm which to rely onto computing a polynomial interpolation. More about it you can find at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm . It is not problem for me to compute the polynomial at some point. There is a lot of sources about it. My problem rely on that I do not want to compute a polynomial at some point, I would like get a polynomials in this form: `a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n`. I do not know how to start. Can you give me some tips ?

Comment: There is material on this in Numerical Recipes, you might want to consult that.
They stress, however, that computing the coefficients is a delicate matter, and it's all to easy to loose a lot of precision that way, and the more points you are interpolating over the more precision you will loose. Do you really really need the coefficients? What for?

Comment: I need have coefficients because I need to compute a derivative of this polynomial.

Comment: You might want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon

Answer (score 2):

A variant of Neville's algorithm allows one to compute some constants (not polynomial coefficients)  for use with another function that can evaluate the interpolating polynomial at any point. This latter function is straightforward to differentiate. The C code below is what I use and I believe it works ok. However I suspect you may be disappointed in how well polynomial interpolation will work unless the data you are feeding it really does come from a polynomial. If you can readily sample the data at many points then it may be better to find a polynomial (expressed as a sum of chebyshev polynomials say) by doing a least squares fit to the data.

```cpp
// fill C (allocated if null) with params for interpolating polynomial
// use params with interp_poly_eval
// !! these are NOT polynomial coefficients. 

double* interp_poly( Int deg, const double* x, const double* y, double* restrict C)
{
double* c = C ?: calloc( deg+1, sizeof *c);
Int i, j;
    memcpy( c, y, (deg+1)*sizeof *y);
    for (i=1; i<=deg; i++) 
    {   for (j=deg; j>=i; j--)
        {   c[j] = (c[j]-c[j-1]) / (x[j]-x[j-i]);
        }
    }
    return c;
}


double  interp_poly_eval( Int deg, const double* c, const double* x, double X)
{
double  p = c[deg];
Int i = deg;
    while( --i >= 0)
    {   p = c[i] + (X-x[i])*p;
    }
    return p;
}

// as above but also returns derivative of the polynomial through pdp
double  interp_poly_eval_d( Int deg, const double* c, const double* x, double X, double* pdp)
{
double  p = c[deg];
double  dp = 0.0;
Int i = deg;
    while( --i >= 0)
    {   dp = (X-x[i])*dp + p;
        p = c[i] + (X-x[i])*p;
    }   
    *pdp = dp;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Do you use a differential quotients ? Can you share with us sources ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. The third routine above computes the derivative of the interpolating polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a class / datastructure that can represent a univariate (over one variable) polynomial. Then it is easy to calculate the actual polynomial (i.e. its coefficients) instead of just the individual points using Neville's algorithm itself, i.e.

```
  P[0,0] = y[0]   ; constant
  P[1,1] = y[1]   ; constant
```

and then recursively

```
  P[a,b] = P[a,b-1] * x[b]/C + P[a,b-1] * -X/C + P[a+1,b] * -x[a]/C + P[a+1,b] * X/C
```

where X is the polynomial "x" (i.e. first-degree monomial) and C is the constant X[b]-X[a].

This gives you the actual polynomial when you follow the recursion in the algorithm as usual.

Note that above, all the arithmetics are for polynomial, i.e. P[a,b-1]*x[b]/C means the polynomial P[a,b-1] multiplied by the constant x[b]/C (the x-coordinate of the b'th point divided by C).

If you want to get an exact result, use arbitrary-precision rational arithmetics package (e.g. GMP for C/C++). Alternatively, calculate using floating-point numbers but you might end up with rounding errors that impact you.